# Adding a pdf page to many pdf files in different folder - Powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to add a pdf page (always the same => C:\Files\page2.pdf) to all pdf files of my folders and subfolders:

I sometimes use this command to find and replace some files by specific ones :

```
replace "C:\PDF\*.pdf" "C:\Folders" /s
```

And I would like something able to find all my pdf in my folders/subfolders (C:\Folders.. with many pdf with 1 page) and to merge a second page (C:\Files\page2.pdf) into all pdf keeping their path and names

Something like this :

```
merge C:\Folders\*.pdf with C:\Files\page2.pdf
```

Do you have any idea to do that simply ? (I am not allowed to install packages, I can only use Powershell build-in commands)

Thanks !

Max

Comment: PowerShell doesn't have a built-in way to modify PDF documents, so in order to do it without a library, you would have to manually modify the byte code of the file, which needless to say, is not very simple.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, even if I hoped it was possible to do it more easily...

Comment: I have thousands of PDF to merge that are in many different folders and I have to do that every month so it has to be done automatically (not possible with Acrobat, no ?)

Comment: What are the best PowerShell addons for PDF ?  I heard of pdftk, is it the best ?